# How to replace "\" using str_replace() in PHP?

Tags: php

I would like to remove all back slashes from strings on my site. I do not wish to use strip_slashes(), because I want to keep forward slashes.

This is the code I am trying:

```
echo str_replace("\", "", "it\'s Tuesday!");
```

I want to find the backslash in any given string and remove it. But, this code is not working right.

Error:

```
syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 25):

The backslash is actually escaping the closing quote in your string.

Try `echo str_replace("\\","","it\'s Tuesday!");`

Comment: Beat me to it :) A handy link to explain what escaping is - http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Comment: these is problem when try  "FBU4061\0258" in double quotes

Answer (score 9):

No sure why you are using `str_replace` to remove `\` use

```
echo stripslashes("it\'s Tuesday!");
```

But if its just an example then

```
echo  str_replace("\\","","it\'s Tuesday!");
```

Please Note that `stripslashes` only remove backslashes not forward

```
echo stripslashes("it\'s \\ \\  // Tuesday!");
```

Outputs

```
it's // Tuesday!
```

Comment: `I want to find the back slash in any given string and remove it.` is that not what you want to achieve

Comment: `I do not wish to use strip_slashes(), because I want to keep forward slashes. `

Comment: stripslashes does remove `forward slashes`. try `var_dump(stripslashes("it\'s // Tuesday!"));`

Comment: does not* remove forward slashes ^

Answer (score 6):

Try and get the result:

```
$str = "it\'s Tuesday!";

$remove_slash = stripslashes($str);

print_r($remove_slash);
```

Output: it's Tuesday!

Answer (score 1):

From the [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) documentation:

> Returns a string with **backslashes** stripped off. (\' becomes ' and so
>   on.) Double backslashes (\\) are made into a single backslash (\).

So you shouldn't worry about the fwd. slashes.

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
echo str_replace("\'", "'", "it\'s Tuesday!");
// It's Tuesday!
```