# replace backslash "\" with a zero "0"

Tags: php, html, html-escape-characters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace “\” using str_replace() in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141406/how-to-replace-using-str-replace-in-php)

How can I replace a backslash with a 0

my code:
`$output = "\x01\x02\x03\x04";

$string = str_replace( '\\' , "0", $output);`

ps. `$output` is an hex string.

Comment: change `'` to `"` around the slashes

Comment: @Baba I agree it is a duplicate. only i have my hex problem and then this solution doesn't work:(

Answer (score 4):

You say that `$string` is an existing string, so I think you need it the other way around (and double quotes instead of single quotes):

```
$output = str_replace("\\", "0", $string)
```

Comment: changed it to "", but not working.
`$output = "\x01\x02\x03\x04";`
after replace it should be:
`$output = "0x010x020x030x04";
when i echo it is empty

Comment: @GertKommer: You can't change "\x01" to "0x01" by replacing backslashes with 0s. Read about escape codes.

Comment: @MarkByers why can i not replace the escape?

Comment: @GertKommer: Your question isn't applicable to the problem you have. Replacing backslashes is not going to work because your string doesn't contain any backslashes. It would be better to state your problem in your question rather than guessing what the solution is and then asking about that.